# How to do post request on a method returns integer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-annotations

in the below example, I am trying to know how in he below code, i am trying to perform POST request given the method initVar ().
I tried to do the post request as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/root/initVar/id/2->error
http://localhost:8080/root/initVar/id?2->error
```

but it does not work when i return Int data type form the method.
please let me know how to fix this error.

please note that this method return Int

**code**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("root")
class Controller1 {

val sayHiLazy by lazy {
    "hi from get"
}

@GetMapping(value = "/sayHi")
@ResponseBody
fun  sayHi() : String {
    return sayHiLazy
}

@PostMapping("/initVar/id")
@ResponseBody
fun initVar(@PathVariable id : Int) : Int {
    return 11
}
}to use spring annotation with koltin in intellij. i used spring annotation with java projects in intellij. but for koltin, it does not work.
```

in the below example, HelloController is underlined with red and i recived the following werror:

```
    classes annotated with @Configurations cannto be implicily subclassed and must be final
```

please let me know how to fi

**Controller1**

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
fun SayHello(): String {
    return "success"
}
}
```

Comment: That can't possibly be the actual erro message you're getting. Don't paraphrase error messages. Copy and paste them. Why do you annotate your controller with SpringBootConfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

1. If You want to use @PathVariable, You have to do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/stuff/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public String doStuff(@PathVariable("id") int id){
    return "id="+id;
}
```

2. You usually write POST method without variables at the end. For such scenarios You should use PUT - https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/
3. I'm not sure if You can return plain integer as a response, but You could optionally wrap your integer into String - `String.valuOf(id);`

Regards